# Emoji Mart Picker categories not responding to click events in Stimulus Controller

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stimulusjs, twemoji, ngx-emoji-mart

I'm integrating the Emoji Mart Picker into a Stimulus controller and encountering an issue: the category icons in the picker are unresponsive to clicks, preventing category switching. The picker initializes correctly, and I can select emojis, but I can't switch categories. There are no console errors.

[image]

Here are the steps I've taken:

- Ensured that Emoji Mart does not list React as a dependency, as my project isn't using React.
- Tried installing React to see if it would resolve the issue, which it didn't.
- Attempted to follow the documentation for non-React environments, but the issue persists.

I'm also unclear on the role of the `data` property during the Picker's initialization and whether it's related to this issue. The documentation at [Emoji Mart's GitHub](https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart/tree/main#-built-for-modern-browsers) doesn't seem to require it explicitly for basic functionality.

Here's my `package.json` snippet for relevant dependencies:

jsonCopy code

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emoji-mart/data": "^1.1.2",
    "emoji-mart": "^5.5.2",
    // ... other unrelated packages ...
}
```

And here's a concise version of my current Stimulus controller setup:

javascriptCopy code

```
// EmojiPicker_controller.js
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';
import * as EmojiMart from "emoji-mart";

export default class EmojiPicker_controller extends Controller {
    // ... other methods ...

    connect() {
        // ... code to check for mobile and initialize picker ...
        this.picker = new EmojiMart.Picker({
            set: 'twitter',
            theme: 'dark',
            onEmojiSelect: (emoji) => this.onEmojiSelect(emoji),
            // ... more options ...
        });

        // ... append to body, set class, and hide ...
    }

    // ... other methods ...
}
```

I've also tried different variations of initializing the picker with `data` passed in, to no avail.

Has anyone experienced this or have suggestions on what could be going wrong?